# Include a layout inside another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a main Layout.
Inside that one I want to include another layout I have.
So, when I add the layout in the main one, only the included layout is showing when I run the application.

This is **main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eff0f0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText,ContentDescription" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0fa2da" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Flight Details"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/header_l" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/header_r" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_inner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/whitebox"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/depart_locations"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="BANGALORE-INDIA(BRL)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#6194c9"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="TO"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/arrival_locations"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/depart_locations"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/to_textview"
                    android:text="CHENNAJ-INDIA(MAA)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#6194c9"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/airline_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/whitebox"
                android:layout_below="@+id/whitebox"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:text="AIRLINE :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/airline_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/airline_textview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/airline_textview"
                android:text="Indigo Preferred"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flight_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/airline_textview"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/airline_textview"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/whitebox"
                android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
                android:text="FLIGHT :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flight_number_class"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/airline_name"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/airline_name"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flight_textview"
                android:text="6E8-277, Class F"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/departure_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/airline_name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/airline_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="DEPARTURE:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/departure_textview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/departure_textview"
                android:text="19:05 Wed, Nov 13"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/arrival_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flight_number_class"
                android:text="ARRIVAL :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/arrival_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrival_textview"
                android:text="19:55"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/e_ticket_pricedetails_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_below="@+id/departure_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="E-TICKET PRICE DETAILS :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pax_price_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/e_ticket_pricedetails_textview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/e_ticket_pricedetails_textview"
                android:text="No Of Passengers:1 Total Amount: Rs.4955"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/contact_person"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pax_price_details"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrival_time" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pax_price_details"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/load" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/myfotterId"
                layout="@layout/footer" >
            </include>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**footer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/myfotterId"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText,DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adult_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="ADULTS"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/pax_tittle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_name_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="FIRST NAME"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/last_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="LAST NAME"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtLast"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="FLIER NUMBER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtflier"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mealpref"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="MEAL PREF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_meal"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seatpref"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="SEAT PREF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/seat_spinner"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cor_department"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="COR.DEPART."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_cor_depart"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cost_centre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="COST CENTER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_cost_center"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="BILLABLETYPE"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_billable"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDR."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobilenumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="MOBILE NO."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/payment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="PAYMENT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#6194c9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the application, it only shows the `footer.xml` layout.
Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to your  -

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/myfotterId"
            layout="@layout/footer" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3">
```

and give value to it according to your requirement.

Comment: where i have to add this line

Comment: still the same issue can check with my xml code i have posted the complete code

Comment: after @+id/imageView3 this i have to include the layout

Comment: have you provided value to that attribute, is it working now ?

Comment: In relativeLayout, you have to specify the view's position relative to other views, but in your xml, the the include block is having only two atrribute only, you have to add "android:layout_below" or other atrribute's like this.

Comment: can u suggest me what other i have to add in that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44222/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-pooja-dubey)

Comment: use android:layout_height="xxdp"

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 <include
       android:id="@+id/myfotterId"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="37dp" 
       layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Specify as per your requirement

```
         android:layout_height="xxdp"
```

and you will see both the xml .

Answer (score 0):

Your Included `layout` may be covering whole screen, i.e size is large.
Either specify where to position included layout( `"android:layout_below="` or `"android:layout_above="` etc)